# How to update values in a Summary Box?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, elided-forms

## Update

The code below works fine.  Failed update of summary box was from a typo in the actual code.  Admins can delete this question if needed.

---

For a summary box that includes a calculated value like the length of a list.

```
myObject /: myObject[assco_][key_String] := assco[key] 

myObject /: 
 MakeBoxes[obj : myObject[assco_], 
  form : (StandardForm | OutputForm)] :=
 Module[{above},
  above = {
    {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"One: ", assco["One"]}]},
    {BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"List Count: ", Length@assco["List"]}]}
    };
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[myObject, obj, None, above, {}, form, 
   "Interpretable" -> Automatic]
  ]
```

When I create an instance it has the correct length of the list.

```
ClearAll[m]
m=myObject[
   Module[{lst=Range@4},
     <|"List":>lst,
       "Append"->Function[AppendTo[lst,#]],
       "One" -> 1
     |>
]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, after I update the list the length in the summary box does not update.

```
m["Append"][5];
m["List"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

The list is updated but the summary box still shows a count of 4.

```
m
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I get the Length to recalculate? I have tried wrapping `Length@assco["List"]` in `Dynamic` but that has no affect.

Comment: `m["List"] = Range@10` does not update `m`.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add tag. One moment; on mobile at the moment.

Comment: @CarlWoll Added the tag I forgot to include. Thanks.

Comment: My comment still applies. Your code doesn’t mutate `m`

Comment: @CarlWoll Perhaps I've made my minimal example too minimal. Will update later today when back at a computer.

Comment: @CarlWoll Okay, both minimal and working now. Wolfram Cloud on mobile to the rescue. LOL

Answer (score 7):

The SummaryBox stuff is just a distraction. Your code:

```
m["Append"][5];
```

does not change `m`. Hence, the summary box will show no change. Returning to your first example:

```
m["List"] = Range@10
```

This could be made to work with the MutationHandler framework. For example:

```
SetAttributes[myObjectHandler, HoldAll];
myObjectHandler[Set[(m_Symbol?myObjectQ)[key_String], rhs_]] := With[
    {new=Association[First @ m, key->rhs]},
    Set[
        m,
        myObject[new]
    ]
]

myObjectQ[m_] := MatchQ[m, _myObject]
myObject/:myObject[assoc_][key_String]:=assoc[key]

Language`SetMutationHandler[myObject, myObjectHandler]
```

Then:

```
m = myObject[<|"One"->1,"List"->{1,2,3,4}|>];
m["List"] = Range @ 10;
m
```

> myObject[<|"One" -> 1, "List" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}|>]

Comment: In OP after `m["Append"][5]` then `m["List"]` does indeed return the updated list so I'm not sure what mean when you say it does not update `m`.

Comment: Okay, no need to change my OP code.  There was a typo in my real code that was stopping the evaluation of the count.  Will delete this question.